# C++, Remove duplicate items

Tags: c++, duplicates

What is wrong in this code? I am trying to remove duplicate elements from the user defined container.

```
template <typename Item>
struct TList
{
    typedef std::vector <Item> Type;
};

template <typename Item>
class GenericContainer
{
    protected:
            typename TList <Item>::Type items;
};
```

There is a method removing duplicate elements in container specialized for Item * (ie items are dynamically allocated):

```
template <typename Item>
template <typename Sort, typename Equal>
void Container <Item * >::remove ( typename TList <Item *>::Type ::iterator it_begin, typename TList <Item *>::Type ::iterator it_end,     Sort sort, Equal equal )
{           //Sort items, ok 
    std::sort ( it_begin, it_end, sort );

            //Apply unique, OK
    typename TList <Item *>::Type ::iterator i_new_end = std::unique ( it_begin, it_end, equal );

            //Delete items after new end of container, OK
    for (typename TList <Item *>::Type ::iterator i_item = i_new_end ; i_item != it_end; i_item ++)
    {
        delete *i_item; //call destructor
    }

            //Erase duplicate items
    this->items.erase ( i_new_end, it_end );

            //Another sort, Exception: Acces in free memory
    std::sort ( it_begin, i_new_end, sort );

);
```

I can not find the problem in line

```
            //Another sort, Exception: Acces in free memory
    std::sort ( it_begin, i_new_end, sort );
```

or lines before...

```
Error log:
Access in freed memory in process: sw.exe(line 796)
```

Thanks for your advice.

**Updated question:**

I translate the code with another compiler (MSVS 2010) and checked items of vector. Here are the results:

Input dataset: 628 items.

```
A) std::sort ( it_begin, it_end, sort );
```

628 items

```
B) typename TList <Item *>::Type ::iterator i_new_end = std::unique ( it_begin, it_end, equal );
```

612 unique items

```
C) for (typename TList <Item *>::Type ::iterator i_item = i_new_end ; i_item != it_end; i_item ++)
{
    delete *i_item; //call destructor
}
```

To my surprise items since item [595] have been deleted (why not item[613]???). I do not understand such strange behavior...

Comment: That's a good question: what is wrong with the code? Why do you think it is incorrect? Does it not yield the result you expect? Does it crash? Does it not compile? Have you stepped through the code in a debugger to see where the issue occurs?  [From a correctness standpoint, this function looks rather scary and not exception-safe:  have you considered using one of the Boost Pointer Containers?  They are well-tested and widely used.]

Comment: @James There is a note about access in free memory, you probably missed it...

Comment: At the second sort: What is `this`? What is `this->items`? what does all of that have to do with `it_begin`? Why aren't you sorting from `it_begin` to `i_new_end`?

Comment: @James: I have highlighted this error outside the code...

Comment: @Lump: Sorry for the typo, I correct it...

Comment: I think you need to attach a debugger and step through it to figure out what is causing the problem:  my best guess is that you have mismatched iterators or invalidated iterators and you're stomping on memory somewhere.  On an unrelated note, unless you have some very unusual sort function, the last `sort` is unneccessary:  `unique` preserves the relative ordering of the unique elements, so the resulting range is guaranteed to be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

My bet is that not only do some values appear more than once, some individual objects appear more than once in the sequence.

When you `delete` all the duplicate values, you destroy some of the objects that remain in the sequence.

The second sort (which is unnecessary, since `unique` does not rearrange things as it removes duplicates) accesses every object, so it immediately steps on the ones which were just `delete`d.

One possible solution is to `sort` the pointers in both ranges resulting from `unique`. Use `set_difference( i_new_end, it_end, i_begin, i_new_end, i_sequence_inserter )` to find the objects that actually need to be freed — assuming they aren't still being used anywhere else.

Or, just use smart pointers, or no pointers at all :v) .

---

### Edit:

See my comment — the best solution is likely to eliminate the use of pointers entirely.

Anyway, here is a sample `set_difference` solution, this one using a custom iterator instead of a sequence inserter.

```
template <typename Item>
template <typename Sort, typename Equal>
void Container <Item * >::remove ( typename TList <Item *>::Type ::iterator it_begin, typename TList <Item *>::Type ::iterator it_end,     Sort sort, Equal equal )
{           //Sort items, ok 
    std::sort ( it_begin, it_end, sort );

            //Apply unique, OK
    typename TList <Item *>::Type ::iterator i_new_end = std::unique ( it_begin, it_end, equal );

    // Now sort the sub-ranges on pointer values to identify duplicate pointers
    std::sort( it_begin, i_new_end );
    std::sort( i_new_end, it_end );

    // delete all pointers that appear only in the set of duplicate values to be erased
    struct deleter {
        deleter &operator *() { return *this; } // assignment to target is assgn. to iter
        deleter &operator =( Item *rhs ) { delete rhs; return *this; }
        deleter &operator ++() { return *this; } // increment is no-op
        deleter &operator ++(int) { return *this; } // increment is no-op
    };
    std::set_difference( i_new_end, it_end, it_begin, i_new_end, deleter() );

            //Erase duplicate items
    this->items.erase ( i_new_end, it_end );

            //Another sort, Exception: Acces in free memory
    std::sort ( it_begin, i_new_end, sort );

);
```

Comment: Sounds likely.  Also, with shared_ptr, it's ok to destroy individual handles to the real object, since it won't be deleted for real, until the last shared_ptr is gone.  So I second the recommendation to use smart pointers, and I would specifically recommend shared_ptr.

Comment: I have a suspicion, if there are lots of duplicate values, that the objects themselves aren't too large. Rather than have the overhead of pointers at all, my top recommendation is to ditch them and populate the arrays directly with the objects. Already it looks like they're mixing and matching object-vectors with pointer-vectors.

Comment: @Robo: I still think the problem is the same. Here is some code.

Comment: Thanks for for your code, but there is a small problem... Using  std::sort( it_begin, i_new_end ) results in empty difference and  std::sort( it_begin, i_new_end, Sort ) in exception: sequences are not sorted :-(.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like iterators used in last call to `std::sort` may be invalid. Probably `it_begin`. Can you try using `this->items.begin()` instead?

Comment: But how could the have been invalidated? `erase` invalidates only iterators after the first erased element.

Comment: @Philipp - that's right. And `it_begin` continues pointing to the beginning of the vector after the sort operation, I wondered if it would point to the element that was at the beginning before the sort operation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the passed in iterators aren't actually from `this->items` but from some other container.

Another possibility is that `delete *i_item` is causing the problem and it only shows up in the final line as a delayed reaction.

EDIT: One other option that comes up way more often than you'd expect is that your `sort` predicate doesn't obey strict weak ordering. Could you show the code for that?

Answer (score 0):

After a little testing, I think `i_new_end` is invalidated by the `.erase()` call.

According to [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/), it **should** still be valid -- only pointers after i_new_end are supposed to be invalidated.  But VisualC++ apparently doesn't follow that.  It almost does the right thing, i_new_end and end() both point to the same location in memory, but `_Mycont` is reset to zero for `i_new_end`, which invalidates the pointer.

That is, even though they point to the same address,  this fails:

```
  if (i_new_end._Myptr == end()._Myptr)  // yes, they're the same
  if (i_new_end == end())  // boom.  exception
```

So, try this:

```
// remember next-to-last item
typename TList <Item *>::Type ::iterator nextlast = i_new_end - 1;

//Erase duplicate items
this->items.erase ( i_new_end, it_end );

// reset i_new_end
i_new_end = nextlast + 1;

// Now this line should not throw
std::sort ( it_begin, i_new_end, sort );
```

Also keep in mind the memory issues mentioned by Potatoswatter.